# MS Access issue with subform not populating properly

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am having an issue with a subform that I am filtering with a Combobox. when I created my example with a blank form the setup works properly, but once I add the data source to the form the subform doesn't work as intendend[image]

if you see the top is how it works properly and the bottom is what happens when I add the source

here is what i did:
[image: setup]

```
Private Sub Combo0_AfterUpdate()

Dim SQL As String



'SQL = "select keywordID, issueID from tblIssueKeyword where keywordID = " & Me.Combo0

SQL = "select * from tblIssueKeyword where keywordID = " & Me.Combo0

Me.tblIssueKeyword_subform.Form.RecordSource = SQL


End Sub
```

the form doesn't have a recordset

the Combobox is just a just of numbers representing the keyword ID. in my other example I generate the keyword list from a query but found out with this example it also isn't working.

and the only thing that changes is this:
[image: change]

and I need that data source for my main form

**update:**
I noted that the issue only happens when I put the tickets table. if I just put another table that I got the issue is not there... could it be that relations are wrong?

[image]

Comment: Is first image a filtered dataset? You show KeywordID as text in form yet you show a number in combobox.

Comment: yes, that is because when I created that table I chose to use a lookup field for the keywordID, instead of showing the keyword it's showing the keyword itself.

Comment: Are you using INNER JOIN? Try LEFT or RIGHT.

Comment: sorry @June7, in the simple example I don't use that, even in the subform the row source doesn't use an inner join... would it help if I post the whole project somewhere?

Comment: Posting links for files to download not appreciated on SO. There are other forums that do encourage providing files.

Comment: understood... I was thinking that this might be a bug as well, I am only adding the source for the main form and the subform is being populated by my own query so nothing should overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found my answer... seems like a table was created by mistake that had certain relationships with other tables.

when I was cleaning my tables I found this and deleted it, and tried again it worked.